# Remapping right command key to right alt in Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout, keymap

For my keyboard layout, I've grown used to having they key right next to my space be Alt-Car (right). Now that I'm on a Mac keyboard, it's Command. Is there any way to map only the right command key to alt-car (right)?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [keyremap4macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) ?

By checking the option:

```
Change Command_R Key (Right Command) > Command_R to Escape
```

I am using the right command as meta/alt key throughout mac os.

Comment: Just installed the software, now called Karabiner, to use on Emacs. Unfortunately it's a little large at 9 megs just to remap one key, but works very smoothly, and was able to set the remap (Command-R to option) to only happen in Emacs and a few other apps. Níííce!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) to remap the modifiers.

Comment: That does not take into consideration left or right position of the command key.